# Reference request on "Simplicial" sets with all maps instead of only monotone ones.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Let $[n]=\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, $[0]=\emptyset$ and $\Sigma_{mn}$ be a set of all maps from $[m]$ to $[n]$, ($\Sigma_{0n}$ consists of a single map and $\Sigma_{no}=\emptyset$ for all $n>0$). Also let $[N]=\{[n]\}$, $\Sigma =\bigcup\Sigma_{mn}$ and $S=\langle[N],\Sigma\rangle$.

Now consider a  "pseudo-diagramme" in **Sets** corresponding to $S$, i.e.  a family of (non-empty) sets $(D_n)_{n>0}$ and a family of maps $\pi=(\pi_\sigma)_{\sigma\in \Sigma}$, $\pi_\sigma:D_n\to D_m$ for $\sigma\in \Sigma_{mn}$ (composition and identity may be not preserved).

This kind of structures are  closely related to simplicial sets where instead of arbitrary maps are taken only monotone maps and composition and identity map are preserved. So a structure from above (without level $0$) can be regarded as a simplicial set  with extra maps $\pi_\sigma$ corresponding to permutations $[n]\to[n]$.

I am looking for reference on such structures in literature, which should exist already somewhere in mathematical practice.

Comment: The best name for these is presheaves on $FinSet^{op}$

Comment: @Joe Moeller I do not agree with $FinSet^{op}$, at least identities and compositions may be not preserved.

Comment: I heard somewhere that this variation of simplicial sets are called $\Gamma$-sets in contrast with $\Delta$-sets, which are simplicial sets. But I have no reference for such name and googling gives me nothing yet.

Comment: $\Gamma$ is the opposite category of the category of finite *pointed* sets, and I believe is called *Segal's Category* in many places. A skeleton of this category consists of the pointed sets $\underline n=\{0,1,\dots,n\}$, with basepoint $0$, for $n\geq 0$. The maps between these objects are the pointed maps of sets. i.e. each map $\underline m\rightarrow\underline n$ sends $0$ to $0$, but is otherwise arbitrary. This is obviously different to what you describe, but observe that by taking disjoint basepoints you get an embedding of your category into $\Gamma$.